# How do we know how exactly user cancelled the dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I use a cancellable dialog fragment with `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`. Now I want to distinguish two cases:

- user cancels the dialog using **Back button**;
- user cancels the dialog by **touching outside** of it.

Both actions lead to invocation of both `onCancel()` and `onDismiss()` listeners. Also these two listeners accept `DialogInterface` as a parameter, to there no any "event state" to check how exactly user has **`cancelled`** the dialog.

So what can I do?

Comment: You could override onBackPressed to know if the user has pressed the back button.

Comment: For first one : you can dismiss the dialog in side OnBackPressed().                      
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {dialog.dismiss();
 }

Comment: which dialog you are using?

Comment: @AlexeyGorovoy Are you using non-model dialog?

Comment: @Fustigador, thanks, your idea helped me to solve my problem. If you want, you could write your proposal again as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Sushrita, sorry, that guy was quicker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if the user has pressed the back button of the device, override the method onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 //here you could set a boolean to know if the user pressed the back button, and react accordingly when the dialog is closed.
backPressed=true;
}
```

For example.